# Swiftのこのクロージャーみたいな記述について質問です

Tags: swift

(質問1)
下のキャプチャ(a),(b)にある書き方はクロージャーなのでしょうか?

クロージャーは以下の様な記述だと思っていまして、(a)はクロージャになると思うのですが、
(b)の記述はそうでないということでしょうか。

```
var hogeHoge = { (parameters) -> return type in
    statements
}
```

(質問2)
Playgroundで見ると、キャプチャにあるように(a),(b)は実行結果が違います。
末尾に括弧があるかどうかの違いで、文法的にはどういう差になるのでしょうか?
(a)は(b)の()を省略したくらいに思ってます。

よろしくお願いします。

[image: Playgroundのキャプチャ]

Answer (score 2):

(テキストで表現できる質問内容は画像の貼り付けではなく、できるだけテキストにしてください。回答者側のPlaygroundなどにコピペするだけで事象が再現できれば、回答を得られる可能性がより高まります。今回は短いので直接打ち直しましたが。)

まとめて答えた方がわかりやすそうです。

> (質問1)
>   下のキャプチャ(a),(b)にある書き方はクロージャーなのでしょうか? 
>   (質問2)
>   Playgroundで見ると、キャプチャにあるように(a),(b)は実行結果が違います。
>   末尾に括弧があるかどうかの違いで、文法的にはどういう差になるのでしょうか?

(a) `{ return 10 }`の部分がクロージャーで、`hoge`にはクロージャーが代入されます。
(b) `{ return 10 }`の部分がクロージャーで、`()`は、そのクロージャーを呼び出すことを表します。`foo`にはそのクロージャーを呼び出した結果が代入されます。

> (a)は(b)の()を省略したくらいに思ってます。

クロージャーそのものを操作対象として変数に代入したりメソッドのパラメータに渡すのと、そのクロージャーを呼び出すのとはしっかり区別するようにしてください。Swiftでは、パラメータを取らない関数(メソッドやクロージャーも含めて)を呼び出す場合の`()`は省略できないため「()を省略したくらい」で意味が変わらないように感じられているとしたら大変危険です。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございました、おかげですっきりしました。(今回みたいなコードの場合はキャプチャでなくてテキストにするようにします)

Answer (score 0):

b のほうは末尾の `()` のために定義された関数(クロージャー)を呼び出しています。
結果として定数値 10 が返ってきているのです。

また今は気にしなくても良いかもしれませんが、
どちらも厳密にはクロージャーにはなっていません。
関数を定義、利用しているだけです。

よって回答は以下のとおりです。

> 下のキャプチャ(a),(b)にある書き方はクロージャーなのでしょうか?

どちらも厳密にはクロージャーではありません。a は関数を定義しています。
b は関数を定義した上で即時実行しています。

> 末尾に括弧があるかどうかの違いで、文法的にはどういう差になるのでしょうか?

括弧があることで、直前の関数が呼び出し、実行されています。

なおキャプチャの例がなぜクロージャーとはいえないのかについては [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A3) より以下を引用して説明に代えさせていただきます。

> 引数以外の変数を実行時の環境ではなく、自身が定義された環境（静的スコープ）において解決することを特徴とする。

Comment: ありがとうございます！おかげですっきりしました。クロージャーの概念に関しても、もう少し理解を深めたいと思います。